# how to insert a default value at zero position in model type list List<DeviceSimNoModel> show in drop down button in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have one drop-down button and there some list data come from JSON and show in drop-down button but I want to add default value ("Select") at zero position in there `list<DeviceSimNoModel>` type of model class in dropdown list button. how to do this?

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'model/device_simno_model.dart';
import 'order.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main()=> runApp(KycForm());

class KycForm  extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "KYC Formm",
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: KycFormScreen(title: "Kyc form"),
    );
  }
}

class KycFormScreen  extends StatefulWidget{
  final String title;
  KycFormScreen({Key key, this.title}): super(key: key);
  @override
  KycFormState createState()=> KycFormState();
}

class KycFormState extends State<KycFormScreen>{
  Icon cusIcon =Icon(Icons.search);
  Widget cusSearchBar= Text("Order List");
  List<String> _list = [];
  String checkedValue;
  BuildContext context;
  String sUrl= "https://fasttracksoft.us/api_v2/device_installation/";
  final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  List<DeviceSimNoModel> deviceSimnoList;
  var params;
  var response;
 // var controller = new MaskedTextController(mask: '(000) 000 0000');
  DeviceSimNoModel _dropdownValue;
  String _errorText;
  TextEditingController phoneController = new TextEditingController();
  var listZero ="Select";

//  List<String> _listString = [
//    "Ac",
//    "Fuel Sensor",
//    "Power",
//    "Panic",
//    "Camera",
//    "Relay",
//    "Duty Button",
//    "Other"
//  ];

  List<String> _listString = [
    "Other",
    "Duty Button",
    "Relay",
    "Camera",
    "Panic",
    "Power",
    "Fuel Sensor",
    "Ac"
  ];
  // var singleline;
  List<bool> selected = [];
  bool isLoading=false;
  var tmpArray = [];
  Future<List<DeviceSimNoModel>> getDeviceSimnoList()async{
    //deviceSimnoList.clear();
//    setState(() {
//      isLoading=true;
//    });
    final prefs= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    params ="get_engsim.php?id="+prefs.getString('id');
    try{
      response =await http.get(sUrl+params);
      print("sURL:"+sUrl);
      print("param:"+params);
      print("customerID:"+prefs.getString('id'));
      print("url+params:"+sUrl+params);

      if(response.statusCode==200){
        deviceSimnoList= deviceSimNoModelFromJson(response.body);
        print("responce:"+deviceSimnoList.length.toString());
        if(deviceSimnoList!=null){
//          setState(() {
//            isLoading=false;
//          });
        }
      }
    }catch(e){
      return deviceSimnoList;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getDeviceSimnoList();
//    deviceSimnoList.add(DeviceSimNoModel(mobileNo: 'Select'));
//    _dropdownValue=deviceSimnoList[0];
//    phoneController.text = _dropdownValue.mobileNo;
    setState(() {
      for (int i = 0; i < _listString.length; i++) {
        _list.insert(0, '${_listString[i]}');
        selected.insert(0, false);
      }
    });
  }

    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OrderScreen()),
            );
          },
        ),
        title: cusSearchBar,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            //tooltip: 'Search',
            //icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
            //Don't block the main thread
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                if(this.cusIcon.icon==Icons.search){
                  this.cusIcon=Icon(Icons.cancel);
                  this.cusSearchBar=TextField(
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: "Search here",
                    ),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                    ),
                  );
                }else{
                  this.cusIcon =Icon(Icons.search);
                  this.cusSearchBar= Text("AppBar");
                }
              });
            },
            icon: cusIcon,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body:Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 15, 15),
          child: ListView(
//          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
//          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

            children: <Widget>[
//            Padding(
//                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, left: 30.0,bottom: 10.0,right: 20.0)),

              Text("Order ID",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,

                ),
              ),

              Text("ORD/12345",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  //fontSize: 20.0,

                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 15),
              Text("IMEI Number",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,

                ),
              ),
              Text("1234567890",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  // fontSize: 20.0,

                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 15),
              Text("Serial Number",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,

                ),
              ),
              Text("ASP134508351A1985",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  // fontSize: 20.0,

                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 15),
              Text("Customer Name",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,

                ),
              ),
              Text("SAKHA CONSULTING WINGS PVT.LTD",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  // fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 15),
              Text("Customer Mobile Number*",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,

                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: 200.0,
                    height: 60.0,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, left: 0.0,bottom: 10.0,right: 0.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        //labelText: 'User Name',
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 15),

                  Container(
                    width: 100.0,
                    height: 60.0,
                    //color: Colors.green,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, left: 0.0,bottom: 10.0,right: 0.0),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      child: Text('SEND OTP'),

                      onPressed: () => {},
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              // SizedBox(width: 15),
              Container(
                width: 100.0,
                //height: 60.0,
                //color: Colors.green,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, left: 0.0,bottom: 10.0,right: 0.0),
                child: Text("Fill OTP*",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: 200.0,
                    height: 60.0,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, left: 0.0,bottom: 15.0,right: 0.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        //labelText: 'User Name',
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        //height: 2.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 15),
              Container(
                width: 100.0,
                //height: 60.0,
                //color: Colors.green,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, left: 0.0,bottom: 10.0,right: 0.0),
                child: Text("Vehicle No*",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: 200.0,
                    height: 60.0,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, left: 0.0,bottom: 15.0,right: 0.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        //labelText: 'User Name',
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        //height: 2.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                ],
              ),

              Container(
                width: 100.0,
                //height: 60.0,
                //color: Colors.green,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, left: 0.0,bottom: 10.0,right: 0.0),
                child: Text("Action Taken",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,

                  ),
                ),
              ),
              new ListView(
                // padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: <Widget>[
                  _list.isNotEmpty
                      ? Wrap(
                    children: _list.map(
                          (item) {
                        var index = _list.indexOf(item);
                        return IntrinsicWidth(
                          child: Container(
                            //padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0),
                            width: 110,
                            height: 40,
                            child: Card(
                              child: InkWell(
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Checkbox(
                                          value: selected[index],
                                          onChanged: (bool val) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              selected[index] = val;
                                              if (val == true) {
                                                tmpArray.add(checkedValue);
                                                print("selectedcheckbos"+tmpArray.toString());
//                                                checkedValue = item;
//                                                print("selectedcheckbos"+checkedValue);
                                              }
                                            });
                                          }),
                                      Expanded(child: Text(item)),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ).toList(),
                  )
                      : Container(),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 15),
              Text("Device Mobile Number *",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),

              TextField(
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 15),
              DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new InputDecorator(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: false,
                        hintText: 'Select',
                        //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
//                      labelText:
//                      _dropdownValue == null ? 'Where are you from' : 'From',
                        errorText: _errorText,
                      ),
                      isEmpty: _dropdownValue == null,
                      child: new DropdownButton<DeviceSimNoModel>(
                        value: _dropdownValue,
                        isDense: true,
                        onChanged: (DeviceSimNoModel newValue){
                          print('value change');
                          print(newValue);
                          setState(() {
                            _dropdownValue = newValue;
                            phoneController.text = _dropdownValue.mobileNo;
                          });
                        },
                        items: deviceSimnoList?.map((DeviceSimNoModel value) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem<DeviceSimNoModel>(
                            value: value,
                            child: Text(value.mobileNo),
                          );
                        })?.toList()?? [],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Text("Upload Documents",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),),
              Container(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 90.0,
                      width: 160.0,
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            //color: Colors.green,
                              border: Border.all(
                                color: Colors.green,
                                width: 2,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0))),
                          child: new Center(
                            child: new Text("ID PROOF",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 22),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                          )
                      ),
                    ),

                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          width: 150.0,
                          child: Text("ID Proof *",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.green,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 160.0,
                          height: 50.0,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, left: 5.0,bottom: 10.0,right: 0.0),
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            child: Text('TAKE PIC'),
                            onPressed: () => {},
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),

                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 90.0,
                      width: 160.0,
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            //color: Colors.green,
                              border: Border.all(
                                color: Colors.green,
                                width: 2,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0))),
                          child: new Center(
                            child: new Text("RC *",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 22),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                          )
                      ),
                    ),

                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          width: 150.0,
                          child: Text("RC *",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.green,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 160.0,
                          height: 50.0,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, left: 5.0,bottom: 10.0,right: 0.0),
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            child: Text('TAKE PIC'),
                            onPressed: () => {},
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),

                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 90.0,
                      width: 160.0,
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            //color: Colors.green,
                              border: Border.all(
                                color: Colors.green,
                                width: 2,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0))),
                          child: new Center(
                            child: new Text("DEVICE *",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,
                                fontSize: 22,
                              ),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                          )
                      ),
                    ),

                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          width: 150.0,
                          child: Text("DEVICE *",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.green,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 160.0,
                          height: 50.0,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, left: 5.0,bottom: 10.0,right: 0.0),
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            child: Text('TAKE PIC'),
                            onPressed: () => {},
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),

                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my Model class.

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final deviceSimNoModel = deviceSimNoModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<DeviceSimNoModel> deviceSimNoModelFromJson(String str) => List<DeviceSimNoModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => DeviceSimNoModel.fromJson(x)));

String deviceSimNoModelToJson(List<DeviceSimNoModel> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class DeviceSimNoModel {
  DeviceSimNoModel({
    this.mobileNo,
  });

  String mobileNo;

  factory DeviceSimNoModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DeviceSimNoModel(
    mobileNo: json["mobile_no"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "mobile_no": mobileNo,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list with your default value then addAll from your JSON list

```
List<DeviceSimNoModel> myList= <DeviceSimNoModel> [];
myList.add(DeviceSimNoModel('Select'));
myList.addAll(ListFromJSON); //Your list from JSON
```

Comment: Thanks Sir for reply But Sir, if I add  this  line    myList.add(DeviceSimNoModel('Select'));    then it create problems in  my DeviceSimNoModel model class . .